# How to set pgsql as the default database for laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

So, I am new to laravel and I want to configure it to use pgsql as the defaut database. These are how my files look like:
.env
[image: .env]
database.ini
[image: database.php]
 This error shows up whenever I try to use the database:

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
>   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 3306?

Please help me out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: by default pgsql uses port `5432`. Can you update the `DB_PORT` in `.env` file & try

Comment: You should check out the migrations documentation found on the [laravel](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations) website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already connecting to postgres, what you have to do is, on your `.env` file, change the port to

```
DB_HOST=5432
```

What I do usually, is to remove that DB_PORT line, and let Laravel choose the default according to the connection:

```
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
```